# Complete theory of arithmetic?

Tags: logic

I read in another post ([Why don't we use Presburger's arithmetic instead of Peano's arithmetic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109457/why-dont-we-use-presburgers-arithmetic-instead-of-peanos-arithmetic)) the following exposition:

> Godel's incompleteness theorem, philosophically (and morally) speaking it says that a consistent theory cannot have all the following properties:
>
> - Can be handled algorithmically (not too complicated)
> - Interesting as a foundational theory (can prove useful statements)
> - Complete (every statement over it is provable or disprovable)

I am wondering if there is any notable extensions of PA that satisfies the last two properties mentioned above? Alternatively, is there a different set of axioms that satisfies the last two properties mentioned above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most interesting complete extension of PA is of course the complete theory of the natural numbers: $$\text{Th}(\mathbb{N}) = \{\varphi\text{ a sentence in the language of arithmetic}\mid \varphi \text{ is true in }\mathbb{N}\}$$

This theory is complete because for any sentence $\varphi$, either $\varphi$ or $\lnot \varphi$ is true in $\mathbb{N}$, so $\varphi\in \text{Th}(\mathbb{N})$ or $\lnot\varphi \in \text{Th}(\mathbb{N})$. And it's certainly interesting: it can prove everything PA can and more - in fact, it answers all questions of number theory that can be expressed as first-order sentences in the language of arithmetic!

The deficiency of this theory as a foundation for mathematics is that we have no way to understand what the axioms are, i.e. whether $\varphi$ or $\lnot \varphi$ is an axiom for each sentence $\varphi$. That is to say, it fails the first property on your list: it's too complicated.

Comment: (+1) But how is "a sentence in the language of arithmetic" formally defined?

Comment: @Jam For that, I recommend picking up just about any textbook in logic - or the Syntax section of the Wikipedia page on "first-order logic"

Comment: Thanks; I found some relevant reading. The main drawback of learning from SE is missing fundamentals.

Comment: @JIARUIQU Yes: Gödel's incompleteness theorem implies this.